# How are convolution cobordism kernels used for the SU(K) sparse graph isomorphism problem?

Tags: group-theory, convolution

I hav homework question... If $K$ is a convolution cobordism kernel, then the $J$th $SU(K)$ tangent fiber must be pairwise compact. How does use this fact to prove graph isomorphism of $SU(K)$ under sparse coding constriant?

Comment: Out of interest, what course does this homework question come from?

Comment: Its from my math course